# How to find a basis of polynomials through linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

So, say I have the set of all polynomials of degree at most 3. I could find a basis for this using the standard bases, however, I would like to find a basis such that it contains no polynomials of degree less than 2. Would I need to use linear transformations? Such as $T(x^2), \ T(x^3)$? bit confused!

Answer (score 2):

You can even find a basis that consists only of degree 3 polynomials.
This problem is equivalent to finding a basis in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that the first component of each basis vector is nonzero. Something like the columns of
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
& 1\\
&&1\\
&&&1
\end{bmatrix}
should suffice. In terms of polynomials, this basis is
$$x^3,x^3+x^2, x^3+x, x^3+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$span \{1,x,x^2,x^3\} = P^3$$

$$span \{-x^2+1,-x^2+x,x^2,x^3\} = P^3$$

It remains to verify that $\{-x^2+1,-x^2+x,x^2,x^3\}$ is linearly independent